# UIKit Default Colors

Tags: swift

I want to get the light grey color of a UINavigationBar and set it as the background color of a UIView. However, it's not accessible. I've made an outlet to the UINavigationBar as navigationBar and navigationBar.backgroundColor! and navigationBar.barTintColor! crashes due to nil value. Of course, I could enter RGB values manually but I would like to access them directly.[image]

The dark grey should be the same as the light grey on the picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get default light Gray :

```
    UIColor.lightGrayColor()
```

Is your VC embedded in Navigation Controller ? Or you just put UINavigationBar on ViewController in IB ?

You can use UIAppearance to change default appearance of UI (I'm using it in viewDidLoad just as an example better put in application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) ):

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var navigationBar: UINavigationBar!{
        didSet{
            navigationBar.delegate = self
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.redColor()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}

extension ViewController : UINavigationBarDelegate {

    func positionForBar(bar: UIBarPositioning) -> UIBarPosition {
        return .TopAttached
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: But lightGrayColor() is different from UINavigationBar color. The UINavigationBar color is self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 248.0/255.0, green: 248.0/255.0, blue: 248.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you.  Can you provide more code and explain once more what do you want to achieve ? Because self.view is probably UIView not UINavigationBar. And on the picture you've provided I see UIStatusBar and UINavigationBar

Answer (score 0):

You can use DigitalColor Meter that is integrated with Mac OS X. Launch that application then move your mouse to a position of image that you want to get color info.

[image]